# How do I store a value from an API call with node.js Express and Mikeal's npm-request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

I've just started experimenting with node Express and wanted to display some text from an API (that I made in Ruby/Sinatra) in my HTML. I can `console.log()` the text I want, but I'm having problems saving it to a variable to call in my `ejs` files. How do I take a value from JSON that I got my calling my API and place it on my page?
Here is my code.

Here is my main Js file.

---

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var routes = require('./routes');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/about', routes.about);

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('look at port 3000')
})
```

Here is my Index Route

---

```
var request = require('request');
var resq = request("http://ancient-falls-7604.herokuapp.com/users/1/posts", function(error, response, body) {
  console.log (JSON.parse(body)["user_posts"][1]["post"]["body"])
}) 
// this thing I just console.logged is what I want saved to a var

exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('main', {
    title: 'Some Random Title',
    sinatra: "JSON CALL WILL EVENTUALLY GO"
  });
};
```

and finally here is my ejs file

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
<h1> <%= title %></h1>
<p><%= sinatra %></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make your request inside your index method, save it to your variables and call render:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  request("http://ancient-falls-7604.herokuapp.com/users/1/posts", function(error, response, body) {
    var json = JSON.parse(body);
    res.render('main', {
      title: json.user_posts[0].post.title,
      sinatra: json.user_posts[0].post.body
    });
  });
};
```

To make that work, make sure the name of your view file is `main.ejs`, since you are calling `main` in the render method.

Answer (score 0):

For ejs, you will need to use

```
res.render('fileName.ejs', {data: data, moreData: moreData, ...})
```

Then you will be able to access it **inside the specified file** as:

```
<%= data %>
```